# Google Cloud Printer does not find my Google Chrome installation

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using [Google Cloud Printer](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintdriver) in a client's computer to let him print his .docx and .pdf files from his Windows and his printer which is located somewhere else.

It works fine, **Google Cloud Printer** is just, I imagine, some "proxy" that acts as a printer for Windows but instead sends print jobs to **Google Cloud Print**. It also open a window before printing in which it lets you confirm, set preferences etc. That window is just like the Google Chrome printing dialog, but without Google Chrome at all.

I have Google Chrome installed, as that seems to be required (and also because it is used by my client).

Today, however, instead of opening the printing window-dialog, Google Cloud Printer began opening an Internet Explorer page that says: "You don’t seem to have Google Chrome installed":

[image]

As you can see from the image, I do have Google Chrome installed.

I have set Google Chrome as the default browser, restarted the computer, reinstalled the Google Cloud Printer driver, but still the error is the same.